# NLog and logging to database in a repository pattern project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, nlog

In NLog, to target a database for logging, you just enter the database connection, etc and it connects straight to the db and does its stuff. My project uses the repository pattern, which all access to the db goes through the repository. How do I setup NLog to log to my database using the repository? Should I create an `ILoggingRepository`? How do I use this in the NLog configuration?

Or should NLog be doing its connection straight to the db because its a logging framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's good that you are abstracting with a data access layer. However the repository pattern is meant/intended for your domain objects.
Think of logging as service and not as a domain object. Logging can be persisted to various locations. Don't create an ILoggingRepository.
Just configure NLog to persist to the db directly.